# SwiftUI: The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've already extracted this to create a separate view, and I still keep on getting the same compile error message when I try to build.

I can't think how I can break it down further.

```
struct MultiPicker: View  {
    @State var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    let instructionString = ["hours", "minutes"]
    let pickerArray = [Array(0...12), Array(0...60)]

        var body: some View {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0..<pickerArray.count) { column in
                        let selection = column == 0 ? dateComponents.hour : dateComponents.minute
                        Picker(instructionString[column], selection: selection) {
                            ForEach(0..<pickerArray[column].count) { row in
                                Text(pickerArray[column][row].description)
                            }
                        }
                        .pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
                                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width / CGFloat(self.data.count + 2), height: geometry.size.height)
                                        .clipped()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}

struct SlotMachine_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        
        MultiPicker()
    }
}
```

Any suggestions gratefully received, thank you.

Comment: `Picker` takes `selection` as a `Binding`, which it isn't at the moment. You need to have a `Binding` which probably gets `column == 0 ? newDate.hour : newDate.minute` and sets the new date however you would like.

Comment: Yeah, this was the solution, thank you.